# Cocos2d-x RenderTexture the image is black(empty) on Android's gallery

Tags: cocos2d-x, android-gallery, cocos2d-x-3.0

In my app , i'm using a RenderTexture as a Canvas.

I would like to save this canvas to android photo gallery , like this:

The cpp side :

```
void Canvas::saveCanvasCallback(cocos2d::Ref *sender)
{
time_t t = time(0);
struct tm * timeinfo= localtime (&t);


char buffer[120];
  strftime(buffer,120,"image_%d%m%Y%I%M%S.png",timeinfo);


auto callback = [&](RenderTexture* rt, const std::string& path)
{
#if CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID
    addImageToGallery(path.c_str());


#else
      CGameManager_iOSBridge::addImageToGallery(path.c_str());

#endif


};


_target->saveToFile(buffer, Image::Format::PNG, true, callback);

CCLOG("Image saved %s \n", buffer);


}
```

The java side :

```
static  void addImageToGallery (String path) {


    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+path);

    getContentResolver().insert(Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

    me.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            Toast.makeText(me.getApplicationContext(), "Image saved ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    });
}
```

The saved image it's black(empty) in the gallery ( for iOS it works fine) .

I'm working with cocos2d-x V3.3

Please help me

Thanks